# html with several drop downs each with its own show/hide textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html with several drop downs. Depending on the each selection a textarea shows for description. Right now I have a show and hide in javascript for each question. Is there a way to concise this so that I dont have to write show/hide for each question. What I mean is, Is there a way that my javascript will be more concise?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Food Selection</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/3/w3.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#spicyFoodField').on('change', function() {
        if (this.value == 'spicyFoodDesc') {
          $("#spicyFoodDesc").show();
        } else {
          $("#spicyFoodDesc").hide();
        }
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#sweetFoodField').on('change', function() {
        if (this.value == 'sweetFoodDesc') {
          $("#sweetFoodDesc").show();
        } else {
          $("#sweetFoodDesc").hide();
        }
      });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#blandFoodField').on('change', function() {
        if (this.value == 'blandFoodDesc') {
          $("#blandFoodDesc").show();
        } else {
          $("#blandFoodDesc").hide();
        }
      });
    });
  </script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="w3-row-padding" id="spicyFood">
    <div class="w3-third">
      <label class="w3-text-green" for="spicyFoodLabel"><b>Do you like spicy food?</b></label>
      <p>
        <select id="spicyFoodField">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select...</option>
      <option value="spicyFoodDesc">Yes</option>
      <option value="no">No</option>           
     </select>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-twothird">
      <p>
        <textarea class="w3-hover-light-blue" id="spicyFoodDesc" name="spicyFoodDesc" rows="2" hidden> </textarea>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-row-padding" id="sweetFood">
    <div class="w3-third">
      <label class="w3-text-green" for="spicyFoodLabel"><b>Do you like sweet food?</b></label>
      <p>
        <select id="sweetFoodField">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select...</option>
      <option value="sweetFoodDesc">Yes</option>
      <option value="no">No</option>           
     </select>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-twothird">
      <p>
        <textarea class="w3-hover-light-blue" id="sweetFoodDesc" name="sweetFoodDesc" rows="2" hidden> </textarea>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-row-padding" id="sweetFood">
    <div class="w3-third">
      <label class="w3-text-green" for="blandFoodLabel"><b>Do you like sweet food?</b></label>
      <p>
        <select id="blandFoodField">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select...</option>
      <option value="blandFoodDesc">Yes</option>
      <option value="no">No</option>           
     </select>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-twothird">
      <p>
        <textarea class="w3-hover-light-blue" id="blandFoodDesc" name="blandFoodDesc" rows="2" hidden> </textarea>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is certainly a way to achieve what you're after, and my preference is to use a combination of *one* event listener, and `data` attributes.

---

The idea is that you apply one event that fires on the change of *any select*, rather than having one for each.

```
$("select").on("change", ...);
```

---

To find out exactly which one changed, you can use `$(this)`. Therefore, `$(this).val()` will tell us if the dropdown is switching to "yes" or "no".

```
var selectedValue = $(this).val();
```

---

We can add the parameter `data-for-id` to each description, and set it to the ID of the associated select. For example, if you have a select with an id of `mySelect`, the textarea would have `data-for-id="mySelect"`.

```
<select id="spicyFoodField">
    ....                
</select>

<textarea data-for-id="spicyFoodField" />
```

---

Now we've created a link between our select and its textarea. Let's implement that in our jQuery code, so that when the select gets changed, it knows what textarea to look for:

```
//Set the associated text area to whatever textarea has 
//the same data-for-id as the changing select list
var $associatedTextarea = $("textarea[data-for-id=" + $(this).attr("id") + "]");
```

---

Finally, we can implement our logic to hide the area, or show the area:

```
if (selectedValue == "yes") {
  $associatedTextarea.show();
} else {
  $associatedTextarea.hide();
}
```

---

Now, any time we want to add a new Select / Textarea, all we have to do is put `data-for-id="associated-select-id"` on the `textarea`, and the code will handle the rest.

**Complete example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {            
    $("select").on("change", function() {      //When a select changes
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();     //Check its new value

        //Get associated textarea
        var $associatedTextarea = $("textarea[data-for-id=" + $(this).attr("id") + "]"); 
        if (selectedValue == "yes") {
            $associatedTextarea.show();
        } else {
            $associatedTextarea.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/3/w3.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="w3-row-padding" id="spicyFood">
<div class="w3-third">
    <label class="w3-text-green" for="spicyFoodLabel"><b>Do you like spicy food?</b></label>
    <p>
        <select id="spicyFoodField">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select...</option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="w3-twothird">
    <p>
        <textarea class="w3-hover-light-blue" data-for-id="spicyFoodField" id="spicyFoodDesc" name="spicyFoodDesc" rows="2" hidden> </textarea>
    </p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="w3-row-padding" id="sweetFood">
<div class="w3-third">
    <label class="w3-text-green" for="spicyFoodLabel"><b>Do you like sweet food?</b></label>
    <p>
        <select id="sweetFoodField">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select...</option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="w3-twothird">
    <p>
        <textarea class="w3-hover-light-blue" data-for-id="sweetFoodField" id="sweetFoodDesc" name="sweetFoodDesc" rows="2" hidden> </textarea>
    </p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="w3-row-padding" id="sweetFood">
<div class="w3-third">
    <label class="w3-text-green" for="blandFoodLabel"><b>Do you like sweet food?</b></label>
    <p>
        <select id="blandFoodField">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select...</option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="w3-twothird">
    <p>
        <textarea class="w3-hover-light-blue" data-for-id="blandFoodField" id="blandFoodDesc" name="blandFoodDesc" rows="2" hidden> </textarea>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I use the same logic 'data-for-id' for show/hide 'div' by using "div[data-for-id=" ? or there is any other tag that I can use? Thanks

Comment: Yep! `var $associatedDiv = $("div[data-for-id=" + $(this).attr("id") + "]");`

Comment: Consider posting a fiddle. Without knowing what you're doing or what you're trying, I can't really help.

Comment: You have `hidden` on the textarea, but with the new code, you're calling `.show()` on the div. The div is actually never even hidden, it's just not showing (in any case) because the textarea is never visible.